PdfSharpCore Perfomance Adding Image
I am building a .NET 9 MAUI application for Android. The app saves reports in SQLite and stores images in the FileSystem.AppDataDirectory. This data is then used to generate a PDF file within the app. I using PdfSharpCore 1.3.65
I am encountering an issue where the app freezes when attempting to load an image using the following line of code:
var image = XImage.FromFile(photo.FilePath);

Below is the relevant part of the code where the problem occurs:
    private void AddImages(PdfSharpCore.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument, List<Photo> photos)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var photo in photos)
            {
                if (File.Exists(photo.FilePath))
                {
                    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.AddPage();
                    XGraphics xGr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
                    var tmpPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo. Filename);
                    // At this line the app is frozen.
                    var image = XImage.FromFile(photo.FilePath);
                    xGr.DrawImage(image, 10, 10, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }     
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> EntryExitReport(EntryExitReport i)
    {
        try
        {
            using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument())
            {
                PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
                GenerateTableEntry(page, i);
                if(i.Photos?.Count> 0)
                {
                    AddImages(document, i.Photos.ToList());
                }
               // Create a MemoryStream for save the byte array
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    document.Save(stream);
                    return stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error al generar el reporte: {ex.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }


does it freeze indefinitely, or does it eventually resume?  How large is the file?  Can you open it using normal file I/O without problems?  Have you searched the bug list for known bugs?

Indefinitly,  the images size are between 4MB and 8MB. I can use the images in the others parts of the app .

I'd suggest creating a test case and filing a bug in their repo

What type of image? JPG? PdfSharpCore is known to resize JPG images. I have more experience with PDFsharp and PDFsharp does not resize images and handles images in a different way, PDFsharp 6.11 and 6.2.0 Preview should work with MAUI and maybe you want to try this other library..
Does it also freeze in a Windows Console app? It is always good to have a minimal, complete example for the developers to work on.
